# Wordpress theme changed and woocommerce product link not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I changed the theme on the WP site and then the woo-commerce product not working.
It give "HTTP ERROR 500". If I change back the theme this product working fine.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the new theme support woocommerce?

Comment: try updating permalinks on setting section also you can debug your site there might be a conflict with the theme. `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`  on your wp-config.php

Comment: There must be some syntax error within new theme's code. 
Error 500 in WordPress is thrown every time mostly because of some php syntax error or missing methods and/or classes. 
As @Firefog suggested, you should switch to debugging mode by adding that line in wp-config.php to see what is actual cause.

Comment: Thanks Firefog and niklaz for the explanation. After enabling the debug mode it shows  a fatal error: "Call to undefined function genesis() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\genesis-connect-woocommerce\templates\single-product.php"

Comment: @gamini2006 you can either remove the function or find out why this error   in your page. Did you switch theme without genesis framework? You have to install a genesis framework to use genesis child theme

Comment: I disable couple of Genesis related plugins and now it is working fine so far...... Thanks for the help